# Using TimePicker or Datepicker in Durandal template project

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am very new to durandal. I have tried of adding time picker to project as follows.
schedule.js code:

```
define([], function (require) {
var script = require('jquery.ptTimeSelect');
var app = require('durandal/app');

var vm = {
    viewAttached: viewAttached,
};
return vm;

function viewAttached(view) {
    $(view).find('#sample1').ptTimeSelect();
    //$('#sample1').ptTimeSelect();

    console.log("activated schedule module");
    return true;
}
});
```

here jquery.ptTimeSelect is time picker js file.
do i really need to add jquery.ptTimeSelect.js here or some where else.

schedule.html :

```
  <section>
    <p>
        <label>Start</label><br />
        <input id="sample1" class="ui-widget-content" name="s1Time2" value="" />
    </p>

</section>
```

problem i am facing i am getting basic time picker at the bottom of the page. I am not getting where to add js and css files to project. Please help i am very new to this.

I am using timepicker from following link http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To get up and running quickly with a solid timepicker control and durandal you can follow these steps.

Add these scripts to your page in the same order as below order. Add them as standard  tags before you load require/durandal.

1. jQuery http://jquery.com/
2. jQueryUI http://jqueryui.com/
3. this timepicker control (built on jquery ui) http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/
4. The jQueryUI Knockout bindings by Steve Saunderson that heiserman mentioned. https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---jqueryui-widgets

Here is how you might reference the scripts above, these scripts tags should go into your main layout page, index.html or whichever page is hosting your durandal application:

```
<head>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/knockout-jquery-ui-widget.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/App/durandal/amd/require.js" data-main="/App/main"></script>
</head>
```

Then you can simply create a timepicker in your durandal view like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Choose Time" data-bind="jqueryui: { widget: 'timepicker', options: { showPeriod: true }}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your precious reply.I have downloaded jQuery,jQueryUI etc now where i should add these.(how to give reference of these files) in my shcedule.js . Or do i need to give reference of these in other files...

Comment: The easiest way to get started is to reference them directly in the head of your html page. I updated the answer above to show this.

Comment: I tried ur answer now i can see text box only(on click of that no time picker pops) but <head> tag throws an error saying "element title appears too few times". So how can i add <head> tags in schedule.html file..

Comment: Apologies - The <head> part should go into your main layout page or index.html page that houses your entire durandal application.

Comment: Ya thank you.. I have added head content to index.chtml .. but still no luck. in inspect element in chrome i got d error as ""jqueryui binding doesn't recognize 'timepicker' as jQuery UI widget", "views/schedule", Object]".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your script looks like, but I'm not sure it will be able execute correctly against the  in the way you're loading it (as an AMD module).  If you want to continue this way, I would take the ptTimeSelect.js script and load it globally with the other jQuery scripts.

**However**, in a Durandal app, it's generally best to avoid manipulating the DOM directly from within the view model.  The best way is to create a custom ko binding handler and perform your DOM manipulation inside of binding.  That way you don't have to worry about timing issues, and your view model stays isolated from direct UI manipulation.

Thankfully, this isn't as hard as it sounds.  Steve Sanderson put together a simple ko binding that you might be able to use out of the box.  Check out this gist: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---jqueryui-widgets

There's a live jsfiddle demo that's referenced by the link above.  This demo doesn't use Durandal, but the relevant knockout concepts are the same.

There's some good general information on custom bindings here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: Thank u for ur quick reply.As i dont know durandal in depth so can u provide some links or peace of code to have time picker in durandal project. I have added link to code i am using plz go through that.